# Confusion regarding definition of quaternions

Tags: quaternions

I am reading about quaternions and their basic properties from this article [Algebra and Geometry of Hamilton’s Quaternions](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/021/06/0529-0544)

> quaternions are quadruples
> of real numbers $q = (α, β, γ, δ)$ forming a four dimensional
> real vector space $H$ (named after Hamilton).
> In terms of the canonical basis:
> $e = (1, 0, 0, 0), i= (0, 1, 0, 0), j= (0, 0, 1, 0)$
> and $k = (0, 0, 0, 1)  (3)$
> ....

> Since any quaternion is a
> linear combination of the basis quaternions $e, i, j$ and $k$,
> it suffices to specify their products. First, $e$ is taken to
> be the multiplicative identity (sometimes denoted $1$),
> so $eq = qe = q$ for any quaternion $q$. In addition,
> $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = −e$, while
> $ij = −ji = k$, $jk = −kj = i$ and $ki = −ik = j. (4)$

However I do not understand how to obtain the eqns $(4)$ using the forms of $e,i,j,k$ given in $(3)$? Any clue regarding the calculations would be helpful.

Comment: From the possible representation (3) you cannot obtain (4). To do that remember that the vector space $H$ can also be seen as being spanned by three [rotation matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4716259/949989) plus the identity matrix.

Comment: "$e$ is taken to be ..." suggests $(4)$ is a list of definitions, and formula $(5)$ follows from them.

Comment: (4) is part of the definition. It doesn't follow from (3).

Comment: $(4)$ is part of definition. But if $i,j,k$ as given in $(3)$ are part of quaternion then they all should satisfy $(4)$, right?

Comment: (3) doesn't say anything about multiplication whatsoever, it just names the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. (4) is a statement with new content, it is telling you how to define a new multiplication operation.